# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm trying to add a snackBar in order to display a message whenever a user signIn or not.
SnackBar.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import classNames from "classnames";
import CheckCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle";
import ErrorIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Error";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import green from "@material-ui/core/colors/green";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import SnackbarContent from "@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const variantIcon = {
  success: CheckCircleIcon,
  error: ErrorIcon
};

const styles1 = theme => ({
  success: {
    backgroundColor: green[600]
  },
  error: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.dark
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  iconVariant: {
    opacity: 0.9,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  message: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});

function SnackbarContentWrapper(props) {
  const { classes, className, message, onClose, variant, ...other } = props;
  const Icon = variantIcon[variant];

  return (
    <SnackbarContent
      className={classNames(classes[variant], className)}
      aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
      message={(
        <span className={classes.message}>
          <Icon className={classNames(classes.icon, classes.iconVariant)} />
          {message}
        </span>
      )}
      action={[
        <IconButton
          key="close"
          aria-label="Close"
          color="inherit"
          className={classes.close}
          onClick={onClose}
        >
          <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </IconButton>
      ]}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

SnackbarContentWrapper.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    success: PropTypes.string,
    error: PropTypes.string,
    icon: PropTypes.string,
    iconVariant: PropTypes.string,
    message: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  message: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf(["success", "error"]).isRequired
};

const MySnackbarContentWrapper = withStyles(styles1)(SnackbarContentWrapper);

const CustomizedSnackbar = ({
  open,
  handleClose,
  variant,
  message
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        open={open}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MySnackbarContentWrapper
          onClose={handleClose}
          variant={variant}
          message={message}
        />
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
};

CustomizedSnackbar.propTypes = {
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  handleClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  variant: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default CustomizedSnackbar;
```

SignInFormContainer.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SnackBar from '../../components/SnackBar';
import SignInForm from './SignInForm';

const SingInContainer = ({ message, variant}) => {
    const [open, setSnackBarState] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = (reason) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
          return;
        }
        setSnackBarState(false)

      };

    if (variant) {
        setSnackBarState(true);
    }
    return (
        <div>
        <SnackBar
            open={open}
            handleClose={handleClose}
            variant={variant}
            message={message}
            />
        <SignInForm/>
        </div>
    )
}

SingInContainer.propTypes = {
    variant: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {variant, message } = state.snackBar;

    return {
        variant,
        message
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SingInContainer);
```

When I run the application I got this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
at invariant (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:34484:15)
at dispatchAction (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:47879:44)
at SingInContainer (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:79135:5)
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:47343:18)
at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:49010:20)
at beginWork (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:50020:16)
at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:53695:12)
at workLoop (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:53735:24)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:34578:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:9000/bundle.js:34628:16)
```

The problem is due to the SnackBar component. I use the `useState`hooks in order to change the state of the snackBar. Should I use a class and a `componentShouldUpdate` in order to not render multiple times?

Comment: You're probably using Webpack, in which case I'd like to bring to your attention the [devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) option which allows you to locate precisely the error in your original code, instead of locating the error in your bundled code as yyou have now

Comment: Can you check if `handleClose` is called multiple times and if by changing `handleClose={handleClose}` to `handleClose={()=>handleClose}` will solve the problem?

Comment: @Nicholas I tried it but I got the same error

Comment: i also had similar issue, but in my case it was due to stale values from previous renders, i had passed empty dependency array in useCallback & was updating state unnecessarily.

Comment: I had a similar error but that was due to an api whose invocation was failing and there were automatic retires on the api.

Comment: @NinoFiliu That would be great if they had any basic examples for WHERE to make these changes they are talking about. Sounds like you need a PhD in Webpack to even understand what they're talking about. Any chance you can summarize?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

I suspect that the problem lies in the fact that you are calling your state setter immediately inside the function component body, which forces React to re-invoke your function again, with the same props, which ends up calling the state setter again, which triggers React to call your function again.... and so on.

```
const SingInContainer = ({ message, variant}) => {
    const [open, setSnackBarState] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = (reason) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
          return;
        }
        setSnackBarState(false)

      };

    if (variant) {
        setSnackBarState(true); // HERE BE DRAGONS
    }
    return (
        <div>
        <SnackBar
            open={open}
            handleClose={handleClose}
            variant={variant}
            message={message}
            />
        <SignInForm/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Instead, I recommend you just conditionally set the default value for the state property using a ternary, so you end up with:

```
const SingInContainer = ({ message, variant}) => {
    const [open, setSnackBarState] = useState(variant ? true : false); 
                                  // or useState(!!variant); 
                                  // or useState(Boolean(variant));
    const handleClose = (reason) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
          return;
        }
        setSnackBarState(false)

      };

    return (
        <div>
        <SnackBar
            open={open}
            handleClose={handleClose}
            variant={variant}
            message={message}
            />
        <SignInForm/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### Comprehensive Demo

See this [CodeSandbox.io demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/kwly8y4l0v?fontsize=14) for a comprehensive demo of it working, plus the broken component you had, and you can toggle between the two.

Comment: your answer resolves the problem described in the question however the variable `open` always `false`

Comment: @para008 I added a comprehensive [demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/kwly8y4l0v?fontsize=14) to prove that it works as it should.

Comment: I don't find my mistake because `open`always false for me however !!variant is false at the beginning then it becomes true

Comment: @para008 Check out the updated demo. It should fully work now, and simulate when `variant` is not set.

Answer (score 149):

In `SnackbarContentWrapper` you need to change

```html
<IconButton
  key="close"
  aria-label="Close"
  color="inherit"
  className={classes.close}
  onClick={onClose} // change this
>
```

to

```html
<IconButton
  key="close"
  aria-label="Close"
  color="inherit"
  className={classes.close}
  onClick={() => onClose()} // to this
>
```

So that it only fires the action when you click.

Alternatively, you could just curry the `handleClose` in `SignInContainer` to

```js
const handleClose = () => (reason) => {
  if (reason === 'clickaway') {
    return;
  }
  setSnackBarState(false)
};
```

It's the same.

Comment: Thanks, works for me. This is what I was looking for  onClick={() => onClose} .

Comment: Yep,   thanks; update my event call 

from onClick={onClose}
to

onClick={() => onClose}

Worked fine.

Comment: thanks actually even i forgot this, now i remembered.

Comment: can someone tell me what to google in order to understand the difference between onClick={() => onClose} and onClick={onClose}? Thanks!

Comment: Googling something to the effect of "binding inline functions in react" should get you where you need to go. you will have to learn about 'this' in js and currying functions, it's quite a rabbit hole.

Comment: Exactly what worked for me. Simple, yet effective answer. Much obliged.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly I was looking.

Comment: tell us more about the curry technique

Comment: difference between onClick={() => onClose} and onClick={onClose}?

Comment: I am just learning react and this worked for me!

Answer (score 13):

While calling function add event like this

before

```js
 <button onClick={ decrementCount() }>-</button>
```

after

```js
 <button onClick={ () => decrementCount() }>-</button>
```

Comment: This helped me, but why this needs to be done? Just want to clear my concepts as I am new to JS.

Comment: The first example is run immediately and the return value is placed at the call position. The second example is an anonymous function/lambda/closure.

Answer (score 10):

You must link an event in your onClick. Additionally, the click function must receive the event. See the example

```
export default function Component(props) {

    function clickEvent (event, variable){
        console.log(variable);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton
                key="close"
                aria-label="Close"
                color="inherit"
                onClick={e => clickEvent(e, 10)}
            >
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If your this simple code is throwing `Too many re-renders`

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    
    setName("Kushal"); // Throws React Error: Too many re-renders

    return (
      <div>{name}</div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

then use `useEffect` like below

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");

    useEffect(()=>{
        setName("Kushal");
    }, []); // empty array means only once
    
    return (
      <div>{name}</div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an event, before call your handleFunction like this:

```
function SingInContainer() {
..
..
handleClose = () => {
}

return (
    <SnackBar
        open={open}
        handleClose={() => handleClose}
        variant={variant}
        message={message}
        />
    <SignInForm/>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remember if you passed a function with parentheses, the function would execute every time the component renders. To prevent this, try to put `()=>` in front of your function.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've gathered,
It seems like the error is caused when we call so many functions.

> mostly `setState()`

One way around this will be to set the states inside a function instead of calling the `setState` directly by `onClick` for example.

Using a lot of states like this probably causes react to re-render multiple times, causing this error.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, however my scenario was different.
`useEffect(()=>{},[])` saved me from this error.

Answer (score 3):

So basically, you just want to make sure that you're calling your state setter as a callback to an event listener, so that way the function doesn't fire off until there's an action.

Something like this:

```
onClick={() => stateSetterFunction()}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same problem, and the solution is I didn't bind the event in my onClick. so when it renders for the first time and the data is more, which ends up calling the state setter again, which triggers React to call your function again and so on.

```
export default function Component(props) {

function clickEvent (event, variable){
    console.log(variable);
}

return (
    <div>
        <IconButton
            key="close"
            aria-label="Close"
            color="inherit"
            onClick={e => clickEvent(e, 10)} // or you can call like this:onClick={() => clickEvent(10)} 
        >
    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent this error by using hooks inside your function.

Answer (score 2):

THIS ERROR IS BECAUSE YOU ARE USING PARANTHESIS AFTER FUNCTION NAME  IN RETURN.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Count = () => {
    const [num, setnum] = useState(0)

const increment = () => {
    setnum((prev) => {
        return prev + 1
    })
    setnum((prev) => {
        return prev + 1
    })

}

const decrement = () => {
    setnum(num - 1)
}

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
        {num}
        <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
    </div>
)
}

export default Count;
```

DONT USE :::   `onClick= {increment()}   or  onClick= {decrement()}`   in Return Section

Answer (score 2):

just one tip , always call function upon some action like this
`onClick{()=>func()}` and not `onClick{func()}` as the latter might hit up re-render issue due to multiple calls

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling your setState right away when you pass It in, make sure you're *not* setting it like this:

variable={setState()}

instead, do it like so:

variable={setState()}

sometimes, you have your setState in a function and you're calling the function directly when you pass it in which causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case its cause because of wrong `attribute` name `onblur={setFieldTouched('firstName')} -->onBlur={()=>setFieldTouched('firstName')}` . after correcting attribute name error gone

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this. At my place it works without any problem.

```
const handleClose = (reason) => {
  if (reason === 'clickaway') {
    return;
  }
  setSnackBarState(false);
};
```

```
<SnackBar
    open={open}
    handleClose={()=>handleClose(r)}
    variant={variant}
    message={message}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

See That you have included preventDefault() or not. In my case, I forgot to use that and later I find that mistake.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved the same issue and I solved it with the below method:

You might be setting useState variable anywhere outside the function. Just check that, if you find it, then remove it and set it in any other function.
I believe it will work.

Thankyou for reading(: