# Updating state inside a ternary operator in react

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator

I'm using the moviedb api to make an app and i'm having some trouble updating state inside a ternary operator. If i run the following code to check if everything is working there are no problems

```
{(match.params.id === iteminfo[0]) ? console.log("match") : console.log("nomatch")}
```

If the id and iteminfo match , i get match , if they don't i get "nomatch"

when i try and update the state like this

```
{(match.params.id === iteminfo[0]) ? setRemove(true) : console.log("nomatch")}
```

I get the following error

[image]

Is there a way to update the state so it doesn't form this loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265604/uncaught-invariant-violation-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-re)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you must’ve put this ternary inside the render function, which produces a feedback loop. Wrap it inside a useEffect callback will do.