# What causes "Too many re-renders" error in React?

Tags: reactjs, rerender

Many times this error is occurring in my project. When facing this error,  I just delete my code.  I'm not understanding why this error would happen.

[image]

Comment: It's same as this one I guess, you can check answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265604/uncaught-invariant-violation-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-re

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265604/uncaught-invariant-violation-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-re)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the each render you are updating the state and it causes infinite re-render. We could help you if you will share your code.