# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop with my useState in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state

I need to change the state and use it but isn't possible and i don't now whhy !!!!

```
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(false)

    let emailsApplied = []

    candidatures.map(c => {
        emailsApplied.push(c.email)
    })


    let emailSession = ''

    if(session){
        emailSession = session.email
    }

    if(emailsApplied.includes(emailSession)) {
        setValid(true)
    }
```

Comment: This error happens when you unconditionally call `setValid` like you are doing here. Call `setState` only inside a sufficiently strict `useEffect` or event handler to prevent it from immediately triggering another render.

Comment: Why does `valid` even need to be a state? It it's not modified inside a event handler it can be a normal variable

Comment: the section of `if(emailsApplied.includes(emailSession)) {
        setValid(true)
    }` is being called inside the function component body that is forceing React to re-invoke the function again with the same props, which is calling the state setter again, which triggers React to call your function again.... and so on. similar stack overflow case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265604/uncaught-invariant-violation-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-re)

Comment: My useEffect don't change the state like that :

    useEffect(() => {
        // ️ some condition here
        if(emailsApplied.includes(emailSession)) {
            setValid(true)
        }

      }, [valid])

      console.log(valid)

Answer (score 1):

You can use function inside useState to caculate default value for state

```
const [valid, setValid] = useState(() => {
    let emailsApplied = []
    candidatures.map(c => {
        emailsApplied.push(c.email)
    })
    let emailSession = ''
    if(session){
        emailSession = session.email
    }
    if(emailsApplied.includes(emailSession)) return true;
    return false;
})
```