# how to clear received router params while re rendering react native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Route params persists on rerendering which causes infinite rerender loop because the route params is used for state change.

I have two screens the main screen,

```
export default function Login({ route }: LoginProps) {
  const loginfn = (data) => { 
    setInProgressState(true)
    // do login }
  }
  const scannedData = route.params.data
  if(scannedData) { // problematic part
    loginfn(scannedData)
  }

  return {
    {InProgressState && (
      <InProgressAlert/>
    )}
    <QRCodeScanner/>
    <TextInputLogin/>
  }
}
```

The QRCode screen,

```
export default function QRCodeScanner() {
  return {
    <Scanner
      onScan={() => { navigation.navigate(ROUTE.LOGIN, {data: barcode.data}) }}
    />
  }
}
```

Now the problem is because `loginfn` changes state and triggers re render which checks for the if condition again and calls `loginfn` again which results in "Too many rerender" error. I expected the route params to be empty on every rerender after the first render but it is not, which is causing this problem.

The closest I could get was

```js
const scannedData = route.params.data
useEffect(() => {
  if(scannedData) { // problematic part
    loginfn(scannedData)
  }
}, [route.params.data])
```

But this only works once. If the same qr code is scanned again the route param is not changed and thus the `useEffect` is not triggered.

I don't know much React but I can understand there's some anti-pattern lurking somewhere but I am not able to understand what it is. Is there a better way to send data from one screen to another and not persist on rerendering?

Comment: Here, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265604/uncaught-invariant-violation-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-re

Comment: It's an anti-pattern to store passed props/state/etc in local component state, if that is what you are doing. It's a bit unclear what exactly your code is doing though since it is a rather incomplete [mcve]. Can you [edit] to provide more clarity and explain what you are trying to accomplish, and include a more complete code example?

Comment: @alegria I checked that example but the difference for me is changing the state alone is not a trigger to call loginFn while that was the case in that example. Something has to call loginFn for me based on the route params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution still may not be the best.

Instead of `useEffect` which had the problem of not working when the same data is passed in the route params, `useFocusEffect` works every time the page is navigated even with same route params.

```
  scannedData = route?.params.data
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      if(scannedData) { 
        loginfn(scannedData)
      }
    }, [route?.params.data, loginfn]),
  )
```

because `useFocusEffect` triggers the callback every time it gets navigated to and `useCallback` takes care of avoiding the infinite re render loop, because it's dependencies has not changed.